# Почему и куда утекает память при изменении размера кадра

Tags: c#, web-camera, aforge

Я начал изучение C#, пытаюсь вывести изображение с веб камеры на форму. Если не ресайзить кадр то все нормально, но если сделать ресайз, то память моментально заполняется. Подскажите где ошибка.

```cs
    using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
    using AForge.Video;
    using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Things
    {

        public partial class Things : Form
        {
            private readonly FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
            private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideoDevice;
            private Bitmap currentFrame;

            public Things()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
                try
                {
                    foreach (FilterInfo VidCapDev in VideoCaptureDevices)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(VidCapDev.Name);
                        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No camera found. Please connect your camera and click RESET.");
                }
            }

            private void FinalVideoDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                currentFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                ResizeFrame(in currentFrame, out currentFrame);
                if (web_cam_box.Image != null)
                {
                    web_cam_box.Image.Dispose();
                }
                web_cam_box.Image = currentFrame;
            }

            private void ResizeFrame(in Bitmap image, out Bitmap resized)
            {
                ResizeBicubic filterResize = new ResizeBicubic(640, 480);
                resized = filterResize.Apply(image);
            }

            private void Things_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (FinalVideoDevice != null)
                {
                    FinalVideoDevice.Stop();
                }
            }

            private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (FinalVideoDevice != null)
                {
                    if (FinalVideoDevice.IsRunning)
                    {
                        FinalVideoDevice.Stop();
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    FinalVideoDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                    FinalVideoDevice.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideoDevice_NewFrame);
                    FinalVideoDevice.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Если закомментировать вызов функции ResizeFrame, то все нормально.

Comment: Если после `resized = filterResize.Apply(image);` вызвать `GC.Collect();`
то все опять нормально работает, но наверное это не правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при ресайзе создается новый Bitmap, с указателями на данные прошлого. => 
    web_cam_box.Image.Dispose();

Этого Dispose() недостаточно, так как при использовании filterResize создается новый Bitmap. Можно добавить строчку в методе ресайза -

```
resized = filterResize.Apply(image);
image.Dispose();
```

А какая цель ресайза? 
Я бы посоветовал пересмотреть решение на

Предварительный выбор разрешения, которое вернет вам камера (Все доступные режимы работы доступны в FinalVideoDevice.VideoCapabilities, после выбора его нужно установить в VideoResolution) Например, выбор по наибольшей ширине -

```
FinalVideoDevice.VideoResolution = 
FinalVideoDevice.VideoCapabilities.OrderByDescending(x => x.FrameSize.Width).First();
            FinalVideoDevice.Start();
```

И установка режима отображения изображения в pictureBox на растягивания до размеров pictureBox'a -

```
pictureBox.SizeMode =PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```